# <input type="file"> , changing the value

Tags: php, javascript, html

there is sth like this on my website:

> `<input type="file" name="file_1" id="file_1">`

when I click on it and choose a file , is there any property that changes in it? 

if so , can I change it by scripting? (i want it to have a default value)

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a security risk and you can't set it using JavaScript or PHP.